# Convert maven project to submodule of multi module project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I have an existing project which is a single maven project. The SVN path be `root/MySingleProject`.

Now I'd like to create a multi module project (parent), and add the existing as a module. Which steps do I have to perform so that svn history/commits are preserved?

Can I just create a new folder in my svn and copypaste the existing project there? (and then of course create a parent and module pom).
`root/MyMultiModule/MySingleProject`

Would this still maintain the history when checked in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Subversion move command to preserve the history:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html

With TortoiseSVN (Windows) you can drag&drop the folder using the *right* mouse button instead of the left one: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html#tsvn-dug-rename-move